# Why don't they allow users to download stand alone package?

Tags: windows-7, download, instant-messaging, file-download

Usually I use yahoo messenger to chat when I have some free time to meet the people around the world and to come to know different cultures. But for the latest version of yahoo messenger I need to install directly from the web which is a bit difficult because of my net speed. Why some applications now a days designed to install directly from the web?

Anyway here my problem is I need to install the latest version of Yahoo messenger on more than one computer, for that I need to download twice or thrice depending number of computers I want to install. But it consumes more time as my net is slow, some times there is chance to get disconnected at that time I need to start from the beginning again. More over I need to use the data limit more than once for the same application which I don't want.

Is there any way to save my data limit and time by downloading such applications as stand alone for the purpose of reuse?

Comment: currently using windows 7 on my computers and if there are any tricks and Technic to quickly save the downloaded file which it downloads to temp folder (as I found on net which are not working currently), I want to know the steps for that in windows 7

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no way to install YM offline. You could however use another messanger like Miranda which can connect to your existing YM account